# Including files in Clojure without Leiningen: Could not locate file

Tags: java, clojure, classpath

Trying to do a simple clojure program without that includes a function defined in another file. It is unable to find the file in the same directory.

```
helloInclude
    src
        main.clj
        importer.clj
```

**main.clj**

```
(ns main
  (:gen-class)
(:require [importer]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))

(-main) 
(println (func 5 6))
```

**importer.clj**

```
(ns importer
  (:gen-class))

(defn func
    [a b]
    (+ a b 1))
```

Executed from within the `src` directory with:

```
java -jar "Path\To\Clojure\clojure-1.8.0\clojure-1.8.0.jar" -i main.clj
```

Returns error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate importer__init.class or importer.clj on classpath., compiling:(C:\Users\jamesjenkinson\Clojure\helloInclude\src\main.clj:1:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate import__init.class or import.clj on classpath.
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:456)
        at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
        at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
        at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
        at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5697)
        at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5692)
        at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5626.invoke(core.clj:5737)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5736)
        at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5717)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:5774)
        at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5758)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:648)
        at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:5796)
        at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5796)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at src.main$eval3$loading__5569__auto____4.invoke(main.clj:1)
        at src.main$eval3.invokeStatic(main.clj:1)
        at src.main$eval3.invoke(main.clj:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6916)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
        ... 14 more
```

Also tried explicitly calling classpath to be the current directory with:

```
java -classpath . -jar "Path\To\Clojure\clojure-1.8.0\clojure-1.8.0.jar" -i main.clj
```

I am unable to use Leiningen for this. How should I properly reference the file?

**Edit:**
Changed namespaces to top level.

Comment: try removing "src." from both namespaces' declarations. (if src is your root folder) else, if "helloInclude" is root, rewrite `(require [import])` to `(require [src.import])`

Comment: src is the root folder. Removed the `src` from both declarations, still doesn't work.

Comment: you have a wrong namespace syntax. try to rewrite it like this: main: `(ns main (:gen-class) (:require [import]))` , import: `(ns import (:gen-class))` . Also i would rename `import` to something else, since there is `import` in clojure already

Comment: See edits, still not being found.

Comment: there is no "root folder" at all here, because no directory on disk is on the classpath

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm getting you correctly and we have the similar problem which I seem to have solved. My current directory structure is (forgive the humorous nature of things):

```
.
├── chikaka
│   ├── main.clj
│   └── tools
│       └── dog.clj
├── core.clj
└── deps.edn
```

The key for me was `deps.edn` file which had the following contents:

```
{:paths ["."]}
```

Source: https://clojure.org/reference/deps_and_cli#_paths

When you add `paths` to the deps file, each is added the to glorious CLASSPATH that Java likes so much. Then you will have requires like this working for example:

```
(ns chikaka.main
  (:require [chikaka.tools.dog :refer [bark]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` only finds files that are under your classpath. If you want to be able to use require, the path to your code relative to the classpath has to match the package and name of the namespace. The `-cp` arg to java can add directories to the classpath, and the current directory is *not* implicitly in the classpath.

If the file is just `import` it must be directly in the top directory, and its package must be changed so it is a top level namespace. To require it with its current location and package, you must use `src.import` instead of `import`.

Also, top level namespaces are not recommended.

Finally, the proper option to run a `-main` is `-m`.

```
+$ ls
import.clj  main.clj
+$ cat import.clj 
(ns import)

(defn foo
  []
  (println "hello"))
+$ cat main.clj
(ns main
  (:require [import])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (import/foo))
:$ java -cp ~/bin/clojure.jar:. clojure.main -m main
hello
```

Comment: This is being executed from the `src` folder. I've changed the namespaces  to remove the `.src`, still with no luck.

Comment: Also tried executing from the parent folder, both with main in `src` and with main in the parent, with the appropriate namespaces. Also unable to find the file.

Comment: also, the file name must match the namespace - if the ns is `import` the file must be `import.clj` not `importer.clj`

Comment: Yeah, I changed it from import due to leetwinski's comment about import already being a word in clojure. I forgot to edit the namespace on the snippet, but had done it in code. Still no success.

Comment: wait, your current directory isn't even in the classpath

Comment: @JamesJenkinson I have updated the answer to show a working version of what you are attempting, and describing the remaining issues.

Comment: On further reflection - I recommend using `load-file` if you are interested in having a simple top level file file that simply runs with top level side effects. Constructs like `require`, `ns`, `gen-class` and setting the classpath are all designed for reusable and architected code, and are not needed when using `load-file`. Either use `ns` and the classpath and `require` etc. with a proper non-top-level namespace, and ensure you have no top level side effects in your files, or just use `load-file`, but there is no need to mix these approaches.